# Ubuntu 20.04 (Lenovo G5070) Charger plugged in but not charging, tried so many ways but no luck..!

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, charging

Lenovo G5070 - Ubuntu - Charger plugged in but battery is not charging, tried so many ways but no luck.

(It is charging when I do hard reset after login but after couple of movements it is not charging - I think in power management the battery percentage refreshes every 30sec to 60sec - so after refresh it is not charging. I tried with the following steps. 1) Removed battery 2) Hold the power button for 10sec 3) Installed battery and logged in.)

Comment: This is happening with my Lenovo machine too.  Unsure if it’s a coincidence, but it only started when I updated to Ubuntu 20.04.  For me, the charge seems stuck at 4%.  If I plug it in, the system says it’s charging but it stays at 4% (only saying “estimating” for how long it will take to charge fully).  Tried with a different charger, but same issue.

Comment: @PatDevlin You are right..!! exactly the same issue.. did you find any solution?

Comment: Aha!  My machine is set up to dual boot.  Out of curiosity, I loaded it up in Windows, and there the thing charged without issue.  In Ubuntu, it now thinks the battery is at 100%.  So it seems something software-related is going on.  But it’s not clear why it wouldn’t just charge when the machine is off...  It might be that Ubuntu doesn’t *think* the battery is charging despite the fact that it is.  But then why would it think it’s fully charged after booting in Windows...  Hmm...  Also, it could all be just some weird coincidence.  Happy for any insight

Comment: By the way, Ubuntu now thinks my battery is at 91%, but it still mostly just says “estimating...” when it’s trying to figure out how long the battery has until charged/empty.  After a bit, it calculated it will take 2 hours 24 minutes to charge to full (from 91%...).  It still seems confused, but now that I have a workaround (boot in Windows to charge) I’ll probably just wait until some new system update randomly fixes any software issues.

Comment: @PatDevlin Yeah, I understand this but can we fix this any other way, instead booting up with windows?

Comment: @PatDevlin Have any luck?